# Problem running a function with ref vars

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

this is a piece of code I did and for some reason when I call the function monF visual studio gives me the following error :

the best overloaded method match for 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.monF(int[], int, ref int, ref int)' has some invalid arguments

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        public static void monF(int[] a, int size, ref int min, ref int max)
        {
            min = a[0];
            max = a[0];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                if (a[i] > max)
                {
                    max = a[i];
                }
                if (a[i] < min)
                {
                    min = a[i];
                }


            }

        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int arraySize = 0;
            int monMin, monMax;

            Console.WriteLine("Please insert the number of digits you want to compare");
            arraySize = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] monArray = new int[arraySize];

            for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter number " + i + ": ");
                monArray[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            }
            monF(monArray, arraySize, monMin, monMax);



        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the ref keyword when calling the method too:

```
monF(monArray, arraySize, ref monMin, ref monMax);
```